# Springboot - MongoDb: prematurely reach end of stream

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot

I got the following issue when trying to send a big request to server.

```
com.mongodb.MongoSocketReadException: Prematurely reached end of stream
        at com.mongodb.connection.SocketStream.read(SocketStream.java:88) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.4.2.jar!/:na]
        at com.mongodb.connection.InternalStreamConnection.receiveResponseBuffers(InternalStreamConnection.java:494) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.4.2.jar!/:na]
        at com.mongodb.connection.InternalStreamConnection.receiveMessage(InternalStreamConnection.java:224) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.4.2.jar!/:na]
        at com.mongodb.connection.UsageTrackingInternalConnection.receiveMessage(UsageTrackingInternalConnection.java:96) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.4.2.jar!/:na]
        at com.mongodb.connection.DefaultConnectionPool$PooledConnection.receiveMessage(DefaultConnectionPool.java:440) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.4.2.jar!/:na]
        at com.mongodb.connection.WriteCommandProtocol.receiveMessage(WriteCommandProtocol.java:262) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.4.2.jar!/:na]
        at com.mongodb.connection.WriteCommandProtocol.execute(WriteCommandProtocol.java:104) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.4.2.jar!/:na]
        at com.mongodb.connection.UpdateCommandProtocol.execute(UpdateCommandProtocol.java:64) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.4.2.jar!/:na]
        at com.mongodb.connection.UpdateCommandProtocol.execute(UpdateCommandProtocol.java:37) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.4.2.jar!/:na]
        at com.mongodb.connection.DefaultServer$DefaultServerProtocolExecutor.execute(DefaultServer.java:168) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.4.2.jar!/:na]
        at com.mongodb.connection.DefaultServerConnection.executeProtocol(DefaultServerConnection.java:289) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.4.2.jar!/:na]
        at com.mongodb.connection.DefaultServerConnection.updateCommand(DefaultServerConnection.java:143) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.4.2.jar!/:na]
        at com.mongodb.operation.UpdateOperation.executeCommandProtocol(UpdateOperation.java:89) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.4.2.jar!/:na]
        at com.mongodb.operation.BaseWriteOperation$1.call(BaseWriteOperation.java:139) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.4.2.jar!/:na]
        at com.mongodb.operation.BaseWriteOperation$1.call(BaseWriteOperation.java:133) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.4.2.jar!/:na]
        at com.mongodb.operation.OperationHelper.withConnectionSource(OperationHelper.java:422) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.4.2.jar!/:na]
        at com.mongodb.operation.OperationHelper.withConnection(OperationHelper.java:413) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.4.2.jar!/:na]
        at com.mongodb.operation.BaseWriteOperation.execute(BaseWriteOperation.java:133) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.4.2.jar!/:na]
        at com.mongodb.operation.BaseWriteOperation.execute(BaseWriteOperation.java:60) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.4.2.jar!/:na]
        at com.mongodb.Mongo.execute(Mongo.java:845) ~[mongodb-driver-3.4.2.jar!/:na]
        at com.mongodb.Mongo$2.execute(Mongo.java:828) ~[mongodb-driver-3.4.2.jar!/:na]
        at com.mongodb.DBCollection.executeWriteOperation(DBCollection.java:342) ~[mongodb-driver-3.4.2.jar!/:na]
        at com.mongodb.DBCollection.replaceOrInsert(DBCollection.java:420) ~[mongodb-driver-3.4.2.jar!/:na]
        at com.mongodb.DBCollection.save(DBCollection.java:409) ~[mongodb-driver-3.4.2.jar!/:na]
        at com.mongodb.DBCollection.save(DBCollection.java:382) ~[mongodb-driver-3.4.2.jar!/:na]
        ...
```

According to my investigate, this error happens because the connection to MongoDb is not kept alive. So I try to add some config to extend the timeout:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableResourceServer
@EnableDiscoveryClient
@EnableFeignClients
@EnableOAuth2Client
@EnableConfigurationProperties
@Configuration
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
@EnableWebSecurity

public class CodelabArticleServiceApplication extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(CodelabArticleServiceApplication.class, args);
}

@Override
public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    // @formatter:off
    http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/*").permitAll().anyRequest().authenticated();
    // @formatter:on
}

@Bean
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "security.oauth2.client")
public ClientCredentialsResourceDetails clientCredentialsResourceDetails() {
    return new ClientCredentialsResourceDetails();
}

@Bean
public MongoClientOptions mongoOptions() {
    int timeout = 3600000;
    return MongoClientOptions.builder().socketKeepAlive(true).maxConnectionIdleTime(timeout)
            .maxConnectionLifeTime(timeout).maxWaitTime(timeout).socketTimeout(timeout).build();
}

@Bean
public RequestInterceptor oauth2FeignRequestInterceptor() {
    return new OAuth2FeignRequestInterceptor(new DefaultOAuth2ClientContext(), clientCredentialsResourceDetails());
}

@Bean
public OAuth2RestTemplate clientCredentialsRestTemplate() {
    return new OAuth2RestTemplate(clientCredentialsResourceDetails());
}
```

}

For some reasons, It's still **not** working. I wonder if my config was right or there are some additional task to make this work?

Comment: @Bao, check mongo configuration & if possible try to increment the timeout and then see

Comment: How do I increase timeout? Does the code above is not enough?

Comment: So, It will be fixed to 60000 in your case?

Comment: Are you configuring your mongoTemplate yourself? or you are letting springboot to do Autoconfigure for you?

Comment: I have updated the question. I am not the one who setup the project but I think springboot does the config here.